# Please anyone tell me does Spring batch support OrientDb

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

In Spring batch different Readers and writers are there. For `MongoDb` and `Neo4j` there is reader and writer class. But there is no class for `Orientdb`. So how I can configure `Orientdb` with `Spring Batch`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no support for OrientDb, you need to write a custom reader/writer for it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: One small note.  There seems to be a Spring Data project run by OrientDB.  There doesn't seem to be a `CrudRepository` implementation in it, but if they created one, you'd be able to use our `Repository` based readers and writers.  You may want to submit an issue requesting it: https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb